# Upcounter with Momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My problem is that my upcounter lost 1 day.
if i set the endDateTime to 1 year and 1 day before or after today it show the right time, but if i set it to exactly 1 year before today it shows the wrong day and month. And if i put the code of updateTimer to fiddlejs.net and test it if it shows the right time than is everything right.
sorry for my bad english :)

```js
function updateTimer() {
    //change endDateTime to your actual time minus 1 year
    var endDateTime = new moment("2016-04-03 4:00:00");
    var startDateTime = moment();
    var timeLeft = endDateTime + startDateTime;
    var timeLeft = startDateTime.diff(endDateTime, 'milliseconds', true);
    var years = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asYears());
    startDateTime = startDateTime.subtract(years, 'years');
    timeLeft = startDateTime.diff(endDateTime, 'milliseconds', true);
    var months = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asMonths());
    startDateTime = startDateTime.subtract(months, 'months');
    timeLeft = startDateTime.diff(endDateTime, 'milliseconds', true);
    var days = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asDays());
    startDateTime = startDateTime.subtract(days, 'days');
    timeLeft = startDateTime.diff(endDateTime, 'milliseconds', true);
    var hours = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asHours());
    startDateTime = startDateTime.subtract(hours, 'hours');
    timeLeft = startDateTime.diff(endDateTime, 'milliseconds', true);
    var minutes = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asMinutes());
    startDateTime = startDateTime.subtract(minutes, 'minutes');
    timeLeft = startDateTime.diff(endDateTime, 'milliseconds', true);
    var seconds = Math.floor(moment.duration(timeLeft).asSeconds());
    var total = timeLeft;

    if (years < 10) years = "0" + years;
    if (months < 10) months = "0" + months;
    if (days < 10) days = "0" + days;
    if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    return {
        'years': years,
        'months': months,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds,
        'total': total,
    }
}

function animateClock(span) {
    span.className = "turn";
    setTimeout(function() {
        span.className = "";
    }, 700);
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var yearsSpan = clock.querySelector('.years');
    var monthsSpan = clock.querySelector('.months');
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function updateClock() {
        var t = updateTimer();

        yearsSpan.innerHTML = t.years;
        monthsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.months).slice(-2);
        daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2);
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        //animation
        // var daysMonth = moment(t.years-t.months-t.days).daysInMonth('month');
        var spans = clock.getElementsByTagName("span");
        animateClock(spans[5]);
        if (t.seconds == 0) animateClock(spans[4]);
        if (t.minutes == 59 && t.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[3]);
        if (t.hours == 23 && t.minutes == 59 && t.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[2]);
        //if (t.months == daysMonth && t.hours == 23 && t.minutes == 59 && t.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[1]);
        // if (t.total <= 0) {
        //     clearInterval(timeinterval);
        // }

    }
    updateClock();

    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}



var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
#clockdiv {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #2DA2DB;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#clockdiv>div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #991b1f;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

#clockdiv>div:nth-child(2) {
    background: #aa1e23;
}

#clockdiv>div:nth-child(3) {
    background: #bc2025;
}

#clockdiv>div:nth-child(4) {
    background: #cc2027;
}

#clockdiv>div:nth-child(5) {
    background: #dc1f26;
}

#clockdiv>div:nth-child(6) {
    background: #ec1e24;
}

#clockdiv div>span {
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: 'pixel', monospace;
    color: #white;
    text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #000, 2px -2px 0 #000, -2px 2px 0 #000, 2px 2px 0 #000;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<div id="clockdiv">
        <div>
            <span class="years"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Jahre</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="months"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Monate</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="days"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Tage</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="hours"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Stunden</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="minutes"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Minuten</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="seconds"></span>
            <div class="smalltext">Sekunden</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Got a bug in the Momentjs libary with the min version i didnt have any problems